Node.js controller doesn't save UTF8 arabic characters to database
this node.js controller does not save the size.name using utf-8 encoding Arabic characters, even though the rest of data is sent correctly to server with arabic encoding, i have tried to console log the size names and it reads them correctly but when i submit the form the arabic characters becomes unreadable.
//contollers/menuItemsController.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const MenuItem = require('../../models/MenuItem');
const Category = require('../../models/Category');
const Size = require('../../models/Size'); 
const dataPaths = require('../../config/data');
const multer = require('multer');

/////...
function addItem(req, res) {
    upload.single('image')(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Opps! something happend when uploading the image' });
        } else if (err) {
         
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Opps! Internal Server Error' });
        }
        const { category, name, sizes } = req.body;
        const imageSrc = 'Frontend/img/' + req.file.filename;
        const sizePrice = req.body.sizePrice;
        const sizesWithPrices = [];
        Object.keys(sizePrice).forEach(sizeName => {
            const price = sizePrice[sizeName];
            if (price !== '') {
                sizesWithPrices.push({
                    name: sizeName,
                    price: parseFloat(price)
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
        const newItem = new MenuItem(category, name, sizesWithPrices, imageSrc);
        fs.readFile(dataPaths.menuItems, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Opps! Error reading menu items file:', err);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
            }

            const menuItems = JSON.parse(data);

            menuItems.push(newItem);

            fs.writeFile(dataPaths.menuItems, JSON.stringify(menuItems, null, 2), 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Opps! Error updating menu items file:', err);
                    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
                }
                res.redirect(`/admincp/menuitems?token=${req.query.token}`);
            });
        });
    });
}
/////...

<!-- views/admincp/menuData/additem.ejs -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="/admincp/menuitems/add?token=<%= token %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="category" class="form-label">الفئة</label>
                                <select class="form-select" id="category" name="category" required>
                                    <% categories.forEach(category => { %>
                                    <option value="<%= category.name %>"><%= category.name %></option>
                                    <% }); %>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="name" class="form-label">الاسم</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3 d-flex flex-column">
                                <label class="form-label">الأحجام</label><br>
                                <% sizes.forEach(size => { %>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input size-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="<%= size.name %>" name="sizes[]" value="<%= size.name %>">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="<%= size.name %>"><%= size.name %></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control size-price" id="<%= size.name %>-price" name="sizePrice[<%= size.name %>]" placeholder="سعر الحجم" pattern="[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?" title="يرجى إدخال أرقام فقط" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                                <% }); %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="image" class="form-label">اختر صورة (PNG, JPG, JPEG)</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" required>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">إضافة</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

console logged the received data, it loads correctly, i included UTF-8 encoding while posting the request to server.

Could be caused by the way your server encodes requests, do you use body-parser and if you use express, did you use APP.use(express.urlencoded());? (Maybe you need to specify { extended: true})

Yes i'm already using both of them, but the werid thing is that the rest of data i submit to server is saved with no issues in UTF-8 encoding, would this be a frontend issue or backend?

Pretty sure backend, since it has to do with how characters are handled. Try to check if foo  bar mañana mañana this string is encoded correctly.

Still nothing, this is confusing me

What do you mean with still nothing? Was it encoded correctly?

nope not encoded :/

Mh well then we can at least be certain it is an encoding problem. In the addItem function, if you console log the req.body right at the beginning, are the values already corrupted?
